# Analysing text that is read from a file in Java

Tags: java, arrays, file, console, ioexception

I am writing a program that analyses text that is input and calculates the average letter count.
I have it working for when text is entered by the user, but I cannot get it to work for when the text is read from a file.

```
public static void ReadFromFile() throws IOException  {
String filename = "name.txt";
String str = new String(new char[100]);
try{
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(filename);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    while ((str = br.readLine()) !=null) {
    System.out.println(str + "\n");
    }
    br.close();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }
while (c != str.length()) {
    if (str.charAt(c) >= 'a' && str.charAt(c) <= 'z') {
        count[str.charAt(c) - 'a']++;   
    }
    c++;
}
for (c = 0; c<26;c++){
    if (count[c] !=0){
        double num = count[c];
        double denom = str.length();
        double average = num / denom;
        System.out.print((char) (c + 'a') + " occurs " + count[c] + " times in the entered string. Average is ");
        System.out.println(average);
    }}}}
```

I keep getting an error that says

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at MainMenu.ReadFromFile(MainMenu.java:79)
at MainMenu.main(MainMenu.java:25)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Line 79 is "while (c != str.length()) {"

Answer (score 2):

You are reading the entire file in, line by line and printing it to System.out

After you have finished that, you then try to process the data, but you've already finished reading in the file, hence str is 'null' and your program dies.

Comment: That makes sense, I had thought it was something like that. I tried to find another way to read from a file but I couldn't find one.
How would I rectify this?

Comment: Right after you System.out.println(), you should put your logic for looping through the characters.  Not after the loop completes. You'll have a loop within a loop.

Comment: Now it's time for you to practice the most important part of programming -- debugging!  Use the debugger to step through your program and see what's going on!

Answer (score 0):

Earlier in your code, you have this loop:

```
while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(str + "\n");
}
```

This will read lines from your file while `str` is not `null`.
That means that when it stops, `str` *is* `null`.

Since you don't give `str` a non-`null` value after that, you get an NPE when you try to run methods on `str` later in the code:

```
while (c != str.length()) {  // str is null here!
    if (str.charAt(c) >= 'a' && str.charAt(c) <= 'z') {
        count[str.charAt(c) - 'a']++;
    }
    c++;
}
```

My guess from looking at your code is that you want to collect information about each line in the file.  To do this, instead of just printing each line, move your counting logic inside the loop which is reading the file:

```
// read each line from the file
while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(str + "\n");

    // collect character data for this line
    while (c != str.length()) {
        if (str.charAt(c) >= 'a' && str.charAt(c) <= 'z') {
            count[str.charAt(c) - 'a']++;
        }
        c++;
    }
}
```

Then process the count array later in the code as you are already doing.

Comment: I still can't seem to get this to work. Getting an error at the same point.

Comment: What error? What changes have you made to your code?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerExceptionat    MainMenu.ReadFromFile(MainMenu.java:86)
 at MainMenu.main(MainMenu.java:25)

Comment: Did you just add the character checking loop inside the file read loop, or did you *move* the character checking loop inside the file read loop?  The code that was breaking before will still break if left where it was.  You can't call `str.length()` after you've finished reading the file.

Comment: Yeah i have moved it and I am still getting the same errors.

Comment: Ah, I notice your average calculator is also trying to use `str` here: `double denom = str.length();`.  As I said before, you cannot call `str.length()` after you've finished reading the file.  You either need to also move that logic inside the file reading loop (if you want to collect separate information about each line), or store the character count in its own variable (if you want to do the average over all lines).